# Magento xml layouts - before="-" not working in 1.4.2

Tags: magento

I have some custom extensions. They're shown in the right sidebar, and I previously had them appearing directly underneath the sidebar cart, which appears at the top, as it has **before="-"** in the checkout.xml file.

Since upgrading to 1.4.2, my custom extensions now appear at the top of the sidebar. I've added **after="cart_sidebar"** to the extensions xml layouts, but they still appear above the sidebar cart regardless.

Changing the order of the extensions, they only move amongst themselves, always at the top - for example, if I add **after="-"** to any of them, they just appear after the other custom extensions, but still at the top above the cart and other default sidebar items.

Anyone any idea why?

**UPDATE:**

I turned on the "Template Path Hints", and for my custom sidebar blocks, the red text showing the template paths appears further down the sidebar, where the block should be showing, but the actual html of the block is appearing at the top of the sidebar still!

[image]

Comment: When you say you "have some custom extensions" that's really vague. Do you mean you've created a module with some blocks, and when you add those block via layout.xml the rendering order isn't working?  Or are you using some specific custom module that used to automatically insert items into layout a specific location, and now that location behavior has changed?  When you're asking questions around here assume all we know about your setup is a base, generic, Magento install.  You need to inform us of the rest if you want a programming to diagnose your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Before trying to find out what's happening in here you should notice following:

- All Magento modules and extensions are loaded in such an order that they meet their declaration  section requirements (xmls in app/etc/modules/). So that modules that depend on other modules are loaded only after them.
- If modules are equal by their  needs, then priority goes to 'Mage' namespace, then to custom modules namespaces. Inside namespaces priority is given by alphabetical order.
- Module layout configuration is created during module load. So result of "before" and "after" instructions depends on blocks already added by previously loaded modules. I.e. when some block has 'before="-"' instruction - it places block first, but later other blocks from next modules can use their instructions to be attached before this block.

Now let's return to your case. Your problem can have multiple reasons heavily depending on your Magento configuration.

First of all I recommend to

1. Turn off whole cache - so that you'll see all changes instantly
2. Turn off all your extensions and test things only with one of them
3. Turn on default Magento CE theme and skin ("default" package)

Then check following cases:

1. Maybe your layout scheme is modified and your extension not referencing correct block (same as "cart_sidebar" uses) to put self in.
2. Maybe some extension deletes original cart_sidebar block and then puts it last in queue of blocks.
3. Maybe some CSS or JS rules place block only visually before other blocks (check blocks order in original html source)
4. Maybe some extension is modifying layout composition rules. Try to turn only one of them. Then try to turn only other one and check result.

Comment: The thing is, it was working fine before, on 1.4.1.1. Only since upgrading has the behaviour changed.